# Only one custom font being recognized at item 0 in info.plist (xcode iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts, custom-font

I imported three fonts

checked that it all works fine until I add second custom font and so on.

---

If I set up my info.plist in this order (item 0 = KorUB.ttf), only KorUB.ttf is recognized :
[image]

```
UIFont *fontOne = [UIFont fontWithName:@"KorUM" size:10.0f] // not works
UIFont *fontTwo = [UIFont fontWithName:@"KorUB" size:10.0f] // works
```

---

If I change around the order (item 0 = KorUM.ttf) only KorUB.ttf is recognized :
[image]

```
UIFont *fontOne = [UIFont fontWithName:@"KorUM" size:10.0f] // works
UIFont *fontTwo = [UIFont fontWithName:@"KorUB" size:10.0f] // not works
```

What is this? bug? Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Use this code to check either your font is available with correct name or not.
                  for(NSString *fontfamilyname in [UIFont familyNames])
                  {
                             NSLog(@"Family:'%@'",fontfamilyname);
                             for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont                 fontNamesForFamilyName:fontfamilyname])
                             {
                                       NSLog(@"\tfont:'%@'",fontName);
                             }
                 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It installs font, it should not be the case, try to list all Fonts using the code below

```
-(void)listFonts{

    for(NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]){
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", familyName);
        for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]){
            NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", fontName);
        }
    }

}
```

In your case, as per you are using the font like

```
UIFont *fontOne = [UIFont fontWithName:@"KorUM" size:10.0f]; 
UIFont *fontTwo = [UIFont fontWithName:@"KorUB" size:10.0f];
```

**might not work**, because it is not necessary that the **fontWithName** should be same as the name of font **ttf** file name, it can be different, see the list of fonts and use the name listed in the list, it should work.

Cheers.

Comment: If i put item0 as KorUB, i get NSLog as ...(other fonts)... KorUB\nfont000000001ae61848...(other fonts)... and if i change the order as item0=KorUM, i get NSLog as ...(other fonts)... KorUM\nfont000000001ae6187f...(other fonts)... Still only recognizing item0..

Comment: @Joon.P If possible can you send the fonts to me? I will try and let you know?

Comment: I'd love to. where should i send them to?

Comment: @Joon.P Unfortunately your font has problems, see this http://i.imgur.com/4WVEIcS.png. I was trying to install into my macbook, it didn't, change your font with similar font is the only solution.

Comment: that's where the problem was.. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to check whether your font is available with the correct name or not.

```
for(NSString *fontfamilyname in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"Family:'%@'",fontfamilyname);
    for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fontfamilyname])
    {
        NSLog(@"\tfont:'%@'",fontName);
    }
}
```

The font name must be the same as the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes font name may not be what you expect. It could be very different than any of the visible font names that you can see.

Add this snippet of code to log all the fonts available to your app in the console.

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem. I find the solution. please try it.
In your story board set the custom font of label or any view (which font  you are not getting) then run the project. After that you will be able to set the font programmatically as well.